# Checking to see if an element exists on a page, if so execute a function and if not do nothing

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the scenario: I have 2 sets of navigation, main and secondary. The main navigation will always exist on a page and the secondary nav will not always be present. On the pages that DO contain the secondary nav, I want the main navigation to do something on mouseenter and mouseleave only when a class of "affix" has been attached to the secondary nav (after the page has been scrolled down to a certain point, but that is a separate piece of code).

The code I currently have is as follows:

```
var navItem = $('.main-navigation');
var stickyNav = $('.tabbed-sticky-nav.affix');

if (stickyNav == null || stickyNav == 'undefined') {
    doNothing();
    return;
} else {
    navItem.mouseenter(function() {
        console.log("Hover");
    });
    navItem.mouseleave(function() {
        console.log("Out");
    });
}

function doNothing() {
    console.log("Object not found");
}
```

When I run this as it is, the nav items always fire the code whether or not the subnav is on the page. I should probably be first checking if .tabbed-sticky-nav exists on the page, that way if the page doesn't have the secondary nav then don't bother checking for anything on hover. However, if the .tabbed-sticky-nav DOES exist and has the class of "affix" added to it, only then do I want the hover actions of the main nav to potentially apply. How can I change things so this cleanly checks and executes for these circumstances?

Comment: sticky nav is probably not equal to `null` or `undefined`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044/is-there-an-exists-function-for-jquery

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question, but you generally should not compare with a string `"undefined"`, just use the keyword: `something === undefined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery always returns something, so the way to check if the elements exist is to use the [length property](https://api.jquery.com/length/). That will tell you how many elements were returned by the given selector.

```
if (!stickyNav.length){
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, while there were a couple other issues this was the reason I was having difficulty debugging things.